# Wrapping Text in matplotlib / mplsoccer

Tags: python, matplotlib, text

I'm fairly new to coding but, using a few templates and a few minor amendments, I've managed to generate some pretty good visuals for my own purposes.

The current code I'm using is in relation to MPLSoccer/PyPizza and I'm struggling to wrap text in what are fairly long dictionary strings taken from my column names/params, which is resulting in them overlapping.

What am I doing wrong?

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
import io

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

from scipy import stats
import math

from mplsoccer import PyPizza, add_image, FontManager
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from PIL import Image
from textwrap import wrap
URL = "https://i.ibb.co/S6WmBqL/logo.png"
image_data = urlopen(URL).read()
concept_scouting_logo = Image.open(io.BytesIO(image_data))
URL = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/f/fc/Wolverhampton_Wanderers.svg/1200px-Wolverhampton_Wanderers.svg.png"
image_data = urlopen(URL).read()
club_logo = Image.open(io.BytesIO(image_data))
df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\joewo\OneDrive\Documents\Concept Scouting App\FBCSV.csv')
df.head()
Player  Team    Team within selected timeframe  Position    Age Market value    Contract expires    Matches played  Minutes played  Goals   ... Prevented goals per 90  Back passes received as GK per 90   Exits per 90    Aerial duels per 90.1   Free kicks per 90   Direct free kicks per 90    Direct free kicks on target, %  Corners per 90  Penalties taken Penalty conversion, %
0   J. Gvardiol Manchester City Manchester City LB  22  75000000    2027-06-30  18  1641    0   ... NaN 1.32    NaN NaN 0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0   0
1   A. Davies   Bayern München  Bayern München  LB  23  70000000    2025-06-30  18  1547    1   ... NaN 0.87    NaN NaN 0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0   0
2   R. Araújo   Barcelona   Barcelona   RCB, RB 24  70000000    2026-06-30  18  1614    1   ... NaN 1.73    NaN NaN 0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0   0
3   A. Hakimi   PSG PSG RB, RWB 25  70000000    2026-06-30  16  1337    3   ... NaN 0.54    NaN NaN 0.47    0.47    42.86   0.27    0   0
4   T. Alexander-Arnold Liverpool   Liverpool   RB  25  65000000    2025-06-30  21  1822    2   ... NaN 1.73    NaN NaN 1.38    0.20    0.00    2.67    0   0
5 rows × 115 columns

columns_to_keep = ['Player', 'Team', 'Position', 'Assists', 'xA', 'Successful defensive actions per 90', 'Defensive duels per 90', 'Aerial duels per 90', 'Shots blocked per 90', 'Interceptions per 90', 'Successful attacking actions per 90', 'Crosses per 90', 'Dribbles per 90', 'Offensive duels per 90', 'Progressive runs per 90', 'Forward passes per 90']
new_df = original_df[columns_to_keep]
columns_list = new_df.columns.tolist()

print(columns_list)
['Player', 'Team', 'Position', 'Assists', 'xA', 'Successful defensive actions per 90', 'Defensive duels per 90', 'Aerial duels per 90', 'Shots blocked per 90', 'Interceptions per 90', 'Successful attacking actions per 90', 'Crosses per 90', 'Dribbles per 90', 'Offensive duels per 90', 'Progressive runs per 90', 'Forward passes per 90']
new_df.shape
(251, 16)
 
params = list(new_df.columns)
print(params)
params = params[3:]
['Player', 'Team', 'Position', 'Assists', 'xA', 'Successful defensive actions per 90', 'Defensive duels per 90', 'Aerial duels per 90', 'Shots blocked per 90', 'Interceptions per 90', 'Successful attacking actions per 90', 'Crosses per 90', 'Dribbles per 90', 'Offensive duels per 90', 'Progressive runs per 90', 'Forward passes per 90']
player = new_df.loc[new_df['Player']== 'Nélson Semedo'].reset_index()
player = list(player.loc[0])
player = player[4:]
player
[1, 0.74, 8.75, 8.06, 1.84, 0.23, 3.95, 2.3, 2.15, 2.61, 5.91, 2.19, 13.48]
print(len(params),len(player))
13 13
values = []
for x in range(len(params)):   
    values.append(math.floor(stats.percentileofscore(df[params[x]],player[x])))
round(stats.percentileofscore(df[params[0]],player[0]))
48
for n,i in enumerate(values):
    if i == 100:
        values[n] = 99
baker = PyPizza(
    params=params,                  # list of parameters
    background_color="#222222",     # background color
    straight_line_color="#000000",  # color for straight lines
    straight_line_lw=1,             # linewidth for straight lines
    last_circle_color="#000000",    # color for last line
    last_circle_lw=1,               # linewidth of last circle
    other_circle_lw=0,              # linewidth for other circles
    inner_circle_size=20            # size of inner circle
)
fig, ax = baker.make_pizza(
    values,              # list of values
    figsize=(8, 8),      # adjust figsize according to your need
    color_blank_space="same",        # use the same color to fill blank space
    param_location=110,  # where the parameters will be added
    kwargs_slices=dict(
        facecolor="#d70232", edgecolor="#000000",
        zorder=2, linewidth=1
    ),                   # values to be used when plotting slices
    kwargs_params=dict(
        color="#F2F2F2", fontsize=12,
        va="center"
    ),                   # values to be used when adding parameter
    kwargs_values=dict(
        color="#000000", fontsize=12,
        zorder=3,
        bbox=dict(
            edgecolor="#000000", facecolor="#6CABDD",
            boxstyle="round,pad=0.2", lw=1
        )
    )                    # values to be used when adding parameter-values
)

# add title
fig.text(
    0.515, 0.97, "Nélson Semedo - Wolves", size=18,
    ha="center", color="#F2F2F2"
)

# add subtitle
fig.text(
    0.515, 0.942,
    "Percentile Rank vs CB's in Top5 Leagues | 2023/24",
    size=15,
    ha="center", color="#F2F2F2"
)


#fig.text(
    #0.99, 0.005, f"{notes}\n{CREDIT_1}\n{CREDIT_2}", size=9,
    #color="#000000",
    #ha="right"
#)

fig.text(
    0.01, 0.01, f"{notes}\n{CREDIT_1}\n{CREDIT_2}", size=9,
    color="#F2F2F2",
    ha="left", va="bottom"
)


# add image
ax_image = add_image(
    concept_scouting_logo, fig, left=0.4478, bottom=0.4315, width=0.13, height=0.127
)   # these values might differ when you are plotting

# add image
ax_image = add_image(
    club_logo, fig, left=0.02, bottom=0.85, width=0.13, height=0.127
)   # these values might differ when you are plotting
```

I was expecting text to automatically wrap for each param/pizza slice.